# German language string from JSON response is not displaying properly in swift 4

Tags: swift

I am getting German language string in api response. It is like :

```
{ address = "Walliser Str. R?ckhaltebeckenBremen";
 companyName = "Fressnapf Bad T\U00f6lz";
}
```

I need to display these strings into a uilabel in proper German language.
My question is how to encode these string into proper form?? Or is it something needs to be done from server side?? 
Code that I am using for api call:

```
let url = URL(string: "\(globalURL)/apiName")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.timeoutInterval = 30
    let body = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameterField)

request.addValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-api-key")

request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = body

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){(data,response,error)in

    guard let dataResponse = data,
        error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            var jsonResponse : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
            jsonResponse.setValue(false, forKey: "success")
            jsonResponse.setValue(error?.localizedDescription as! String, forKey: "message")
            completion(jsonResponse)
            return
    }
    do{
        var jsonResponse : NSDictionary!
        jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResponse, options: .allowFragments)as? NSDictionary
        print(jsonResponse)
        completion(jsonResponse)
    } catch let parsingError {
        print("an error occurred parsing json data : \(parsingError)")
    }
}
task.resume ()
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you sure about the font which you use does support characters in German ABC?

Comment: The question mark in the address needs to be fixed on the server side.

Comment: What should be the output text for this?

Comment: The `\U00f6` which represents `ö` will be displayed correctly in a label. The question mark which represents `ü` has to be fixed on the server side as already mentioned by Joakim. And please don't use `NS(Mutable)...` collection types in Swift. Use native types.

Comment: @vadian NSMutable is only used if no response from server. Not used to store response

Comment: There is no reason at all to use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift. You throw away the type information and the `var` keyword makes native collection types mutable.